# Delete bigquery table from pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I'm working on script to read data from mongodb, parse the data in spark and write it to Bigquery. I have an use case where based on collection I need to update/re-create bigquery table. But I'm unable to find the exact api to delete the bigquery table

I'm using https://github.com/samelamin/spark-bigquery library to write/append data to bigquery but couldn't find enough documentation to re-create the table. Also looked into Google's big-data-interop library https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop but unable to find the exact api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out the code, you should try with `WriteDisposition` parameter which is passed to [BigQueryDataFrame.scala#L35](https://github.com/samelamin/spark-bigquery/blob/d45c73187392f12b09074248c3fcba9a1c40d436/src/main/scala/com/samelamin/spark/bigquery/BigQueryDataFrame.scala#L35) file. According to other libs ([Python](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.html), [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.html)), if you use [*WriteTruncate* option](https://github.com/samelamin/spark-bigquery/blob/d45c73187392f12b09074248c3fcba9a1c40d436/src/main/scala/com/samelamin/spark/bigquery/package.scala#L14), the action should overwrite the content of the table: "If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data."

So the code like this should work (took from Github's https://github.com/samelamin/spark-bigquery#saving-dataframe-using-pyspark):

```
# Load into a table or table partition
bqDF = bigquery.BigQueryDataFrame(df._jdf)
bqDF.saveAsBigQueryTable(
    "{0}:{1}.{2}".format(BQ_PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, TABLE_NAME),
    False, # Day paritioned when created
    0,     # Partition expired when created
    bigquery.__getattr__("package$WriteDisposition$").__getattr__("MODULE$").WRITE_TRUNCATE(),
    bigquery.__getattr__("package$CreateDisposition$").__getattr__("MODULE$").CREATE_IF_NEEDED(),
)
```

Let us know whether it helped.